# Which Angular or Ionic lifecycle hook to use to get offsetWidth of element after it is rendered

Tags: angular, ionic4

I need to get the width of a `<video>` element which is currently styled to be 100% of the parent height. This means that I can only get the width after the browser has rendered it (or at least I think so).

I am using the `IonViewDidEnter` lifecycle hook as shown below. The problem is that I sometimes get the right dims, and I sometimes get the wrong dims. In other words reloading randomly yields two sets of different results so I'm guessing I'm using the wrong hook.

This is within my component class

```
@ViewChild('video', { static: false }) private videoElRef: ElementRef;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.videoEl = this.videoElRef.nativeElement;
  this.videoWidth = this.videoEl.offsetWidth;
  this.videoHeight = this.videoEl.offsetHeight;
}
```

Which hook or other method should I use to guarantee that I will get the width of the `<video>` element after it has loaded.

Comment: You can try ngAfterViewInit or ngAfterViewChecked

Comment: @Shriniwasb thanks but unfortunately that didn't work. ngAfterViewInit actually made things worse than ionViewDidEnter. I did some console logging and found that ngAfterViewInit fires before IonViewDidEnter.
Regards ngAfterViewChecked, that just fires over and over which is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. This doesn't answer the title question in general cases but it at least covers my own case with a `<video>` tag.

I found that using the video element's `loadedmetadata` event or `loadeddata` event was a quick enough way to get the `offsetwidth` and `offsetheight` without trying to access them early.